# Do I need to use an exact image of a product in Schema markup?

Tags: schema.org

My website provides online services rather than sells actual physical products. What image should I include in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Per https://schema.org/Product specs it should be **An image of the item.** You can set any image you associate with the service you provide. See also the https://schema.org/Service it may fit your needs better.

Comment: thank you for your answer!
Correct me if I'm wrong, but Google does not fully support  https://schema.org/Service